# Воспроизведение треков из списка

Tags: android, list, mediaplayer

Задумка такая: есть плейлист. По нажатию на название трека нужно его воспроизвести. Проблема в том что при воспроизведении каждого последующего трека звук накладывается на предыдущий, получается куча одновременно играющий песен.

```
public class RingtoneFragment extends ListFragment {

public int setTrack = -1;

final String[] trackNamesArray = new String[] {"track1", "track2", "track3"};

final int[] trackPathArray = new int[] {R.raw.music1, R.raw.music2, R.raw.music3};

private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, trackNamesArray);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ringtone, null);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    //в position получаю номер трека

    setTrack = position;

    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), trackPathArray[setTrack]);

    if(mMediaPlayer != null){
        runMusic();
    }else{
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
    }
}

private void runMusic(){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Условие неверное. Должно быть так: если плеер не нуль, то стоп, релиз; потом создаём и запускаем

```
    setTrack = position;

    if(mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
    }

    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), trackPathArray[setTrack]);

    runMusic();
```